# Validate Tier Pricing / Volume pricing using java

Tags: java, math

I want to validate pricing on Salesforce based on volume using Java.

For example: 
Price for 1-1000 quantity is 2.25$ each
Price for 1001-3000 quantity is 2$ each
Price for 3001-5000 quantity is 1.5$ each
So if I purchase 4000 quantity the pricing breakup would be 2.25$ for first 1000, 2$ for next 2000 and remaining 1000 would be priced at 1.5$.
Expected output for `4000` products is = `7750` (2250@2.5$ +4000 @2$ +1500@ 1.5$)

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: what is expected output

Comment: Expected output for 4000 products is = 7750 (2250@2.5$ +4000 @2$ +1500@ 1.5$

Comment: The quantity will never go beyond 5000?

Comment: quantity can go beyond 5000 and accordingly additional discount will be provided. (Have not mentioned discount % above 5000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it using conditional statements like if else :

```
public class cn {
    public static void main(String arf[])
    {
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        int items;
        double sum=0;
        items=in.nextInt();
        if(items<=1000)
        {
            sum=items*2.25;
            System.out.println((int)sum);
        }
        else
        {
            if(items<=3000&&items>1000)
            {sum=2250;
            items-=1000;
                sum+=items*2;
                System.out.println((int)sum);

            }
            else
            {
                if(items<=5000&&items>3000)
                {sum=6250;
                items-=3000;
                    sum+=items*1.5;
                    System.out.println((int)sum);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```